# When Interface A defines Interface B in its method signature

Tags: java, inheritance

... how can I restrict an implementation of A to use a certain implementation of B in the method signature?

***Use Case***

Here is a `Unit` interface and two enums that implement it:

```
public interface Unit { ... }

public enum ForceUnit implements Unit { ... }
public enum MassUnit implements Unit { ... }
```

Which is used by the `Property` interface:

```
public interface Property {

    public void setUnit( Unit unit );    // for example
}

public class Force implements Property { ... }
public class Mass implements Property { ... }
```

Here I want to be able to enforce that:

- `Force` uses only `ForceUnit` in the `setUnit` signature
- `Mass` uses only `MassUnit` in the `setUnit` signature

---

When I try to do this, Eclipse complains:

> The type `Mass` must implement the inherited abstract method `Property.setUnit(unit)`

And promptly suggests two quick fixes:

- make the class abstract, which is not an option since I want to be able to do stuff like `Mass mass = new Mass();`
- add the unimplemented methods with an `@Override` annotation. I don't know if this is the right fix, but to me this smacks of clumsiness.

---

### Questions

- What options do I have to achieve what I want? Would the use of generics help here?
- Why does marking the class as abstract resolve the issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use generics

```
public interface Property<U extends Unit> {

    public void setUnit(U unit );    // for example
}

public class Force implements Property<ForceUnit> {
    @Override
    public void setUnit(ForceUnit unit) { }
}

public class Mass implements Property<MassUnit> {
    @Override
    public void setUnit(MassUnit unit) { }
}
```

Note: This does mean you can still do

```
Property raw = new Mass();
raw.setUnit(ForceUnit.NEWTON); // ClassCastException
```

however this will cause a class cast exception as the compiler is unable to check the raw type at run time.

What you should do is

```
Property<Mass> raw = new Mass();
raw.setUnit(ForceUnit.NEWTON); // doesn't compile.
```

> Why does marking the class as abstract resolve the issue?

Making the classes abstract means that `setUnit(Unit)` hasn't actually been implemented but for an abstract class this is ok.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! This should most definitely work

Comment: I'm noticing something here... I don't need the `@Override` annotation

Comment: @Zaid you never need the `@Override` as there was code written before Java 5.0 which didn't use the `@Override` and it still compiles.